# Is there a way to pass attributes to data source in terraform?

Tags: terraform

I'm trying to tell data.github_ip_ranges to what name to use so I could create a list of CIDRs and my code look cleaner. I was trying to find answers, but no luck so far.

And I'm trying to see if there is a way of passing my variables to it...

```
variable "git_services" {
  default = ["hooks_ipv4", "dependabot_ipv4", "dependabot_ipv6", "git_ipv4", "hooks_ipv6"]
}

locals {
  github_ips = concat(data.github_ip_ranges.git.name) # name is my custom variable
}
```

Here is my original approach

```
locals {
  github_ips = concat(data.github_ip_ranges.git.hooks_ipv4, data.github_ip_ranges.git.hooks_ipv6, 
  data.github_ip_ranges.git.dependabot_ipv4, data.github_ip_ranges.git.dependabot_ipv6)

}
```

Please help if you could. Thank you!

Comment: Not sure it is clear enough what you want to achieve. You want to create your own value for a data source?

Comment: As per the documentation (https://registry.terraform.io/providers/integrations/github/latest/docs/data-sources/ip_ranges) the data source you reference expects no arguments hence you cannot pass any values to it. Additionally, it is not possible to create attributes and/or arguments for data sources and resources unless you are willing to change the source code of the provider.

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand what you're trying to accomplish. You would do it like so:

```
variable "git_services" {
  default = ["hooks_ipv4", "dependabot_ipv4", "dependabot_ipv6", "git_ipv4", "hooks_ipv6"]
}

locals {
  github_ips = distinct(flatten([
    for service in var.git_services:
    data.github_ip_ranges.git[service]
  ]))
}
```

What this is doing is creating a list of lists, where each element in the first level is for a service, and each element in the second level is a CIDR bock for that service. The `flatten` function turns this list of lists into a flat list of CIDR blocks. Since the same CIDR might be used for multiple services, and we probably don't want duplicates if we're using this for something like security group rules, we use the `distinct` function to remove any duplicate CIDR blocks.